# ie states jquery ajax is null when data is returned

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer

I know i am proberly being dumb or something but for the life in me i cannot get this function to work in IE7+, works in every other non IE browser:

/inbox/get_auth_replies (JSON Returned):

```
{"default_message":"Thank you, we have already recieved your request. A member of the team will contact you shortly.","repeated_message":"Thank you for contacting us. A member of the team will contact you shortly."}
```

jQuery:

```
var $keyword_id = 123;
$.post('/inbox/get_auto_replies', {keyword_id: $keyword_id}, function(resp) {
    console.log(resp.default_message);  
    $('#inbox_default_message').val(resp.default_message);
    $('#inbox_repeat_message').val(resp.repeated_message);
}, 'json');
```

in IE reports:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'default_message': object is null or undefined.

I can see it is returning the data but just cannot see/parse it?

I have looked at everything on SO and nothing seems to help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: can you `console.log(resp)`? is it valid json? what content type is your script responding with?

Comment: ummm. I think IE won't recognize console.log(), or would it?

Comment: Is the code inside a jQuery ready function? In IE it can sometimes throw this error when it's trying to execute before the DOM is fully loaded... But @UmairP comment is probably the reason - though console does work for IE8+ I believe, not 7 though

Comment: @dm03514 - I have edited my code, UmairP - it does support it.

Comment: @danrichardson sorry i didnt see your comment, yes its inside an onclick element.

Comment: @KyleHudson - Well, I took the JavaScript (minus the AJAX call) and JSON that you've posted and tried it in IE9 and it ran just fine. There must be something different between this code and your production code since this code runs without a hitch.

Comment: I am confused now as it does appear to be the ajax call :(, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change `$.post` to `$.ajax` and make use of the error callback and log the error.
2. I would suggest changing `var $keyword_id = 123;` to `var keyword_id = 123;` Use `$` before a variable name when indicating that its a jquery dom element

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `jQuery.getJSON` instead? Same structure as the .post (minus the 'json' parameter).
Could then loop through the items to try and work it out and alert/console.log them?
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

It might be a case of not being able to parse the JSON in IE7, does it work in IE9 (if you can try it). I know you mentioned IE7+, but which have you tried? I think there is native JSON parsing in IE8 onwards.